# Why are cloud tasks executed later than the scheduled time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have been using Google Cloud Tasks to execute a function at a specific time, but I have noticed that the some tasks are being executed later than the scheduled time, and are almost always running 2 minutes behind schedule. I have checked the logs in Logs Explorer, but I have not been able to find the root cause of this issue.

I have checked the logs in Logs Explorer, but I have not been able to find the root cause of this issue. There no warning and max attempt also 0.

Comment: How long take the processing on your Cloud Functions?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere

Function which calling from cloud task will take maximum 1 to 3 sec for processing. The batch 1 to 10 only execute late and batch 11 to 20 executed on time.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Batch 1 to 10 => 
scheduleTime: "2023-02-04T14:30:00Z"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-02-04T14:32:42.648183433Z"

Batch 11 to 20 =>
scheduleTime: "2023-02-04T14:45:00Z"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-02-04T14:45:00.723382431Z"